# understanding socket recv behaviour

Tags: sockets, unix

I'm reading the manpage for recv http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv , but it doesn't really answer the questions I have, so I hope I can get some answers here.

I call recv this way:

```
numBytes = ::recv(getSocketId(), pData, nSize, MSG_DONTWAIT);
```

Now the questions are:

1. When the package is bigger than the buffer, recv will read up to nSize bytes and place it in the memory location. the returnvalue would be nSize, right? I can call recv again until all data is received.
2. When the package is smaller than nSize rcv will read as many bytes as are available and then return with a value < nSize && >= 0. Or would recv try to wait until nSize bytes were actually received? If I understand the man page correct, I think this is not the case (at least I hope for it). Or will recv return with -1 and errno = EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK?
3. If recv returns with -1 what happens to the buffer? Will it always stay untouched in that case or could it be that part of the data has already been put into it, but then I would never know how many bytes were transfered, so I assume that this is not the case, right?

What I want to have is, that it reads as many bytes as are available, and then return, giving me the number of bytes transfered. In an additional layer I will construct the actual message, independent of how fragemented it is received. However, I don't want the server to get stuck on a receive call because I can't know what the client is doing and it shouldn't effectively hang the server on one connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. When the package is bigger than the buffer, recv will read up to nSize bytes and place it in the memory location. the returnvalue would be nSize, right? I can call recv again until all data is received.

Correct.

> 1. When the package is smaller than nSize rcv will read as many bytes as are available and then return with a value < nSize && >= 0.

Not quite. It will return > 0 if there is data, 0 if the peer has closed the connection, and -1 if there has been an error, or if there is no data and you are in non-blocking mode.

> Or would recv try to wait until nSize bytes were actually received?

No.

> If I understand the man page correct, I think this is not the case (at least I hope for it).

Correct.

> Or will recv return with -1 and errno = EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK?

Yes, if you are in non-blocking mode and there is no data.

> 1. If recv returns with -1 what happens to the buffer?

Nothing.

> Will it always stay untouched in that case

Yes.

> or could it be that part of the data has already been put into it

No. if you got any data you would get its length, not -1.

> but then I would never know how many bytes were transfered, so I assume that this is not the case, right?

Right.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot, because from the manpage I was not really sure about the state of the buffer and the returncodes involved.